# How to dynamically change images retrieved from a json file in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, dom-events

I am making an angular application which displays medias like audios, videos and gifs. All these data are being fetched from a Json file and are displayed. Now here comes the tricky part :

When the first index is a video, i am triggering the 'ended' event so that it moves to the next index. But when the first index is an image, how shall i change the index , so that the app does not freezes.

Here's the snippet of the code :

```
<body>

  <div *ngIf="is_video; else openImage" class="maxsize">
    <video id=video_player autoplay preload class="maxsize" (ended)="onMediaEnd()" (error)="onMediaError()"
      (suspend)="onMediaSuspend()" autoplay="true">
      <source [src]="getMediaSource()" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>

  <ng-template #openImage>
    <div class="maxsize">
      <img id=image_player [src]="getMediaSource()" class="maxsize" (error)="onMediaError()"
        (suspend)="onMediaSuspend()">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

is_video is a boolean variable which is a global variable.

```
 is_video: boolean = remote.getGlobal("playlist")[this.media_index].video
    ? true
    : false;
```

And i tried something like this in getMediaSource() for getting the first index and using setTimeout() in typescript :

```
 getMediaSource(): any {
    try {
      if (this.is_video == true) {
        return (
          "file://" +
          this.signage_storage +
          getFilenameFromURL(
            remote.getGlobal("playlist")[this.media_index].video
          )
        );
      } else if (this.is_video == false && this.media_index!=0)
        return (
          "file://" +
          this.signage_storage +
          getFilenameFromURL(
            remote.getGlobal("playlist")[this.media_index].image
          )
        );
      else if (this.is_video == false && this.media_index == 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('Test');
          return (
            "file://" +
            this.signage_storage +
            getFilenameFromURL(remote.getGlobal("playlist")[0].image_player)
          );
        }, 10000);
        this.playNextMedia();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

and this the onMediaEnd() which calls playNextMedia(),

```
onMediaEnd() {
    this.playNextMedia();
  }

  playNextMedia() {
    this.nextMediaIndex();
    if (this.is_video) {
      let video_player: HTMLVideoElement | null = <HTMLVideoElement>(
        document.getElementById("video_player")
      );
      video_player.load();
    } else {
      try {
        let image_player: HTMLImageElement | null = <HTMLImageElement>(
          document.getElementById("image_player")
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Caught Error : ", error);
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Triggered setTimeout");
        this.playNextMedia();
      }, 10000);
    }
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Its hard to visualise what is 'freezing' the app. Could you create a Stackblitz example and point out the issue there please? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hrkic3

Comment: App is freezing in the sense that when the first index is an image,then the image gets displayed but it doesn't moves the next index. But if the first index contains a video, then it runs perfectly and moves to the next index as well.

Comment: From what I understand, you have a bunch of video/image files. If the first file is a video, it starts playing and when the video ends you trigger the (ended) observable which then increments the index and starts playing the next file. But if it is an image there is no event to increment the index? Couldn't you start a timer (setTimeOut) for a few seconds and then when the timer fires increment the index?

Comment: A stackbliz example would be helpful to debug your issue.

Comment: @AlvinSaldanha  Yeah it worked out. Thanks